# Can I stop c++ template argument from being deduced?

Tags: c++, template-argument-deduction

It's known that Template argument deduction takes place when you do not explicitly state the template argument, as in

```
template <typename T> void foo(T&& t) {};
```

Now we can invoke either as

`foo(1)`;

`foo('c')`

Or

`foo<int>(1)`;

`foo<char>('c')`

In first set of invocations template argument deduction will happen.
But will there be no template argument deduction in second case where template argument is explicitly specified?

Comment: Yes, if you specify the parameter, the compiler will not try to deduce it.

Comment: With explicit instantiation, it no longer accepts an lvalue argument

Comment: @LWimsey good point, unless the explicit instantiation is with a reference, like: `foo<int&>(i)` or `foo<const int&>(i)` etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `std::type_identity` (added in `C++20`)

```
void foo(std::type_identity_t<T> && t) {}
```

But note that this changes the function signature since the argument is no longer a forwarding reference; ie. it does not accept an lvalue argument, unless you instantiate with an lvalue reference type.

```
foo(1); // error. requires explicit instantiation

foo('c'); // error, requires explicit instantiation

int i;
foo<int>(i); // error, requires rvalue

foo<int&>(i); // ok
foo<int>(42); // ok
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. Here is one way:

```
template<typename T>
struct nodeduce {
    typedef T type;
};
```

Then you use `typename nodeduce<T>::type` instead of T in the parameter list

Comment: Can you please give few examples?